# Is there any method to change the icon for the imshow() window?

Tags: python, opencv

That's the default `cv2.imshow()` window icon:

[image: Default cv2.imshow() window icon]

I'm finishing up a basic project, but want to make it look cleaner by changing the window icon that is displayed. I know it can be done with Tkinter windows, but I wanted to see if there was a more direct way to do it with just the OpenCV library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that using only OpenCV. Its [High-level GUI](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html) only supports minimal functionality, cf. the detailed description:

> While OpenCV was designed for use in full-scale applications and can be used within functionally rich UI frameworks (such as Qt*, WinForms*, or Cocoa*) or without any UI at all, sometimes there it is required to try functionality quickly and visualize the results. This is what the HighGUI module has been designed for.
>
> It provides easy interface to:
>
> - Create and manipulate windows that can display images and "remember" their content (no need to handle repaint events from OS).
> - Add trackbars to the windows, handle simple mouse events as well as keyboard commands.

"Manipulating" windows is limited to naming, moving, resizing them.

(From my personal point of view, OpenCV windows are just for prototyping, nothing you'd use in production.)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with native methods, example in WIN32:

```
// cvGetWindowHandle is CHILD window in opencv_455
static HWND _GetCvWindow(LPCSTR lpWndName) {
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle(lpWndName);
    if (IsWindow(hWnd)) {
        HWND hParent = GetParent(hWnd);
        DWORD dwPid = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwPid);
        if (dwPid == GetCurrentProcessId()) {
            return hParent;
        }
    }

    return hWnd;
}

// param 1: window name, first parameter of imshow
// param 2: resource id
static void _SetCvWindowIcon(LPCSTR lpWndName, WORD wIconId) {
    HWND hWnd = _GetCvWindow(lpWndName);
    if (IsWindow(hWnd)) {
        HICON hIcon = LoadIconW(gs_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(wIconId));
        SendMessageW(hWnd, (WPARAM)WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon);
        SendMessageW(hWnd, (WPARAM)WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIcon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any python solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works on Python for changing the Icon on the top left of the window next to the name:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import win32gui,win32con

#Just a background example using Numpy module.
bg_example = np.full((512,512,3),(0,0,0),np.uint8)

#Showing the GUI of OPENCV
cv2.imshow("MyWindow", bg_example)

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "MyWindow")
icon_path = "my_icon.ico" #You need an external .ico file, in this case, next to .py file
win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_SETICON, win32con.ICON_BIG, win32gui.LoadImage(None, icon_path, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE))

#ESC for exit
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

*The icon on the task bar doesn't change.*

Comment: It works perfect for me. Just in case, I'm using 3.10.4 Python version (64-bits) and 4.5.5 Opencv version.